# Kubuntu 17.04 is missing virtual network adapters

Tags: networking, kde

I am wondering how one adds back the virtual adapters for vlan/teaming/bridge/bonding.  It still existed in 16.10. is this a bug or did some one remove this functionality?

when you go to the connectino editor and click add.  currently there is wired/wireless/wired shared/wireless shared | vpn .....   it used to be wired/wireless/wired shared/wireless shared | virtual adapters ... | vpn ...

Comment: They still exist in my Ubuntu 17.04 system.  Do you have all these packages installed? `network-manager-openvpn
network-manager-openvpn-gnome
network-manager-pptp
network-manager-vpnc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 18.04 came out I revisited this issue and it ended up being a stupid setting in the control pannel to "show virtual settings"

right click on the network icon and select "network settings' under general select "show and configure virtual connections".  after words going in to network configuration now has the options for vlan etc.